# Is there any way to select a value dynamically for a model's related field in runtime?

Tags: python, django

I want to achieve a functionality, where I need to select a django model (e.g from a drop down list), and after selecting one, all the objects of that model shows up.

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    sender = models.(???) # This need to be a field that can store a different model on a run time.
    receiver = models.(???) # same here.
```

Is there any way that I can dynamically first select the model and then pick an object of that list. I have seen this functionality in odoo. But is there anything in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was possible with ajax too, but there also is another way in django which I was searching for.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the many-to-many filed with multiple available choices of "Student" and "Teacher" from another Model.

```
    class UserRole(models.Model):
        STUDENT = 'STUDENT'
        TEACHER = 'TEACHER'
    
        ROLE_CHOICES = (
           (STUDENT, 'student'),
           (TEACHER, 'teacher'),
        )
        role_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)

        def __str__(self):
            return "{}".format(self.role_name)

    class User(AbstractUser):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
        email = models.EmailField(_('email address'))
        role = models.ManyToManyField(UserRole)

    Class Thread(models.Model):
        sender = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        receiver = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This way you can only put available roles in sender and receiver fields of Thread.

Comment: I have already used different models for student and teacher etc, each connected to user one to one because of extra fields in each.

Comment: You need an extra Roles model to do this activity. Also you need only one user model for all type of users whether its "student" or teacher etc. Also Use same UserRole model there with role field.

Comment: Like this model of users.
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'))
    profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(UserRole)

Comment: @Nomi please check the edited answer for better understanding.

Comment: I got the point. Actually what I was tying to find, was a solution that can provide me the functionality that I want achieve, mentioned in the end of the question. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

Use Inheritance for in your Model and map your foreign key to User, and then pass either a teacher of student object.

Comment: my models are not designed this way. I have a user model and a student and a teacher model. And there is one to one relation between student and user, and between user and teacher.